# Add an element to a list past the end of the list in python

Tags: python

Is there a pythonic way to add to a list at a known index that is past the end of the list? I cannot use append, as I'm looking add at an index that is more than 1 past the end. (For example, I want to put a value at x[6] when len(x) == 3).

I have a code that performs actions for sequential steps, and each step has a set of inputs. The users create an input file with these inputs. I store those inputs as a dictionary for each step, then a list of dictionaries to keep the order of the steps. I had just been reading the inputs for each step, then appending the dictionary to the list. I want to harden the code against the steps being out of order in the input files. If the user puts step 6 before step 3, I can't just append. I do not know the total number of steps until after the file has been read. I have a method worked out, but it seems clunky and involves multiple copies.

My kludgy attempt. In this case InputSpam and CurrentStep would actually be read from the user file

```
import copy
AllInputs = []
InputSpam = {'Key',999}
for i in xrange(0,3):
   AllInputs.append(InputSpam.copy())

CurrentStep = 7
if CurrentStep - 1 == len(AllInputs):
   AllInputs.append(InputSpam.copy())
elif CurrentStep - 1 < len(AllInputs):
   AllInputs[CurrentStep-1] = InputSpam.copy()
elif CurrentStep - 1 > len(AllInputs):
   Spam = [{}]*CurrentStep
   Spam [:len(AllInputs)] = copy.deepcopy(AllInputs)
   AllInputs = copy.deepcopy(Spam)
   AllInputs[CurrentStep-1] = InputSpam.copy()
   del Spam
```

Comment: Lists aren't sparse. If you need key-value maps, you want a dict, not a list.

Comment: You can't have a list with index 3 and 6 but nothing in-between. You need to add *something* at those indexes.

Comment: Use a dict instead of a list

Comment: nothing is stopping you from re-sorting the list at the end to keep it ordered internally

Comment: While this isn't exactly what you asked for, you could try to use an OrderedDict instead of a list, so that the elements remain sorted by step (i.e. the key), but you still have gaps in between the steps as you're adding them.

Comment: If you insist on using a list, you can append `None`s up to the index you care about and then come back and fill them in later.  [`more_itertools.pad_none`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.pad_none) can do this for you.

Comment: It is important to maintain the order, so I can't use a dict. The problem with an OrderedDict is that the issue I'm having is that they are specifically not being added in order.

Comment: Why OrderedDict if you can just use a regular dict using the index as key in form `{1: 'foo', 2: 'bar', 4: 'baz'}`. That way you get the best of the two words.

Comment: @white - That could work. Right now I'm using the ordered nature of the list to iterate through the steps:  ````for CurrentInput in AllInputs: do stuff````    I suppose I could switch to something like ````for i in xrange(0,N): CurrentInput = AllInputs[i]: do stuff````

Answer (score 1):

Only after I wrote the answer I notice you use pyhton **2**. Python 2 is unsupported for a long time now. You should switch to python 3. (The following solution is only valid for python 3.)

You can use [`collections.UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList) to crate your own variation of a list like this:

```
from collections import UserList

class GappedList(UserList):
    PAD_VALUE = object()  # You may use None instead
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.data.extend(self.PAD_VALUE for _ in range(len(self.data), index+1))
        self.data[index] = value
```

Inheriting from the `UserList` makes the whole structure to mostly behave like a regular `list`, unless specified otherwise. The `data` attribute gives access to "raw" underlying `list`. Only thing we need to redefine here is `__setitem__` method which cares to assignments like `my_list[idx] = val`. We redefine in to firstly fill in a gap inbetween the end of the current list and the index you want to write in. (Actually it fills the list including the index you want to write to and then re-writes to value -- it makes the code a bit simpler).

You might need to redefine alse `__getitem__` method if you want to handle access to index in the gaps somewhat differently.

Usage:

```
my_list = GappedList([0,1,2])
my_list.append(3)
my_list[6] = 6
my_list.append(7)
my_list[5] = 5
print(my_list)

# output:
[0, 1, 2, 3, <object object at 0x7f42cbd5ec80>, 5, 6, 7]
```